# Using setTimeout() for checking changes in JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am writing an app running inside a browser. Every minute I load a json file from my server with current data and need compare these data with data from the previously loaded json file. If there is any change, I will show new data dynamically inside the app.

I have used a function with a delay for it. Example at the JSfiddle.
However, I am not able to get local variables from the function with the delay into next function, in which I would be able to compare the data.

I have tried create global variables, tried work with scope variables, and even save values in storage. Nothing has been working for me.
Output from the JSON file are objects.

Any help, please?
JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vladoss/r02aLv60/2/

```js
dataUpdates();
var ch1;
     
function dataUpdates() {
    ch = (function() {
      ch = null;
      $.ajax({
          'async': false,
          'global': false,
          'url': "json.json", //non-exisitng json.
          'dataType': "json",
          'success': function (data) {
              ch = data;
          }
        });
        return ch; //current data
    })();
          
    setTimeout(oldValues, 3000);
    function oldValues() {
     ch1 = ch[0]; //old data
    }

    if (ch1 !== ch[0]) { //Here I need be able to read variable ch1.
       console.log(ch1); //ch1 is undefined
       //...
 }
}
setInterval(dataUpdates, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `oldValues` doesn't block!

Comment: You do not understand how asynchronous code works in javascript. I would suggest reading further into that topic.

Comment: why do you have both setInterval and setTimeout? All your code in oldValues should be at the end of dataUpdates. Or where else could it's value change?

Comment: @DanielA.White: but the ajax call does. `async: false`.

Comment: @Oliver It's a "synchronous AJAX call". :)

Comment: Still you should put your processing code into the success callback

Comment: "return ch" is unnecessary there. You are not calling the function and using the return value. You should really understand asynchronous code and function mechanics of js first.

Comment: @Gavriel: I have both setTimeout /interval functions inside one function because I want load the setTimeout function few seconds after the SetInterval function.

Comment: @Scimonster Sure, but setTimeout is not synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by this way. It works fine for me.

```js
dataUpdates();

function dataUpdates() {
 ch = (function() {
     ch = null;
     $.ajax({
         'async': false,
         'global': false,
      'url': "json.json",
      'dataType': "json",
         'success': function (data) {
             ch = data;
         }
     });
     return ch;
 })();

    setTimeout(oldValues, 20000); //run oldValues function after 20s
};

function oldValues() { //save previous ch into variable
     ch1 = ch;
    setTimeout(checkData, 20000);   //wait 20s and compare previous ch(=ch1) with current ch
};

function checkData(){
 console.log(ch[0].Title);
 console.log(ch1[0].Title);
}

setInterval(dataUpdates, 30000); //run dataUpdates function every 30s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare checksums of two json files. For this you can use [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-checksum) . Code structure can be simplified to this.

```
var curCh = null;

function dataUpdates() {
    $.ajax({
      'async': false,
      'global': false,
      'url': "json.json", //non-exisitng json.
      'dataType': "json",
      'success': function (data) {
          var ch = checksum(data);

          // Comparing checksums
          if(curCh != ch) {
              curCh = ch; 

              console.log('new json! do updates here!');
          }
      }
    });  
}   

setInterval(dataUpdates, 5000);
```

Comment: is there possible directly check individual objects inside the json file or only whole json? In my case I have tried compare two individual objects pulled out of one json file. JSON contains 8 objects. (before and after update).

Comment: sure. you can loop through all of the json keys for(var k in obj) { console.log(obj[k]); } And compare desired keys if not all of them.

Comment: Let's say json is obj = { "name": "test", "phone": "123" }. To access it use obj.name or obj.phone. To compare just use if(curObj.name == obj.name) { console.log("true"); }

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle is down. :(

You seem to use both `ch` and `ch1` before they get assigned. In case of `ch1` it's easy to see:

```
if (ch1 !== ch[0])
```

Will get executed almost 3 seconds before you assign a value for the 1st time in oldValues.

And you also use `ch[0]` in 2 places without checking whether `ch` or `ch[0]` are set!

You might try this:

```
setTimeout(oldValues, 3000);
oldValues();
function oldValues() {...
```

So `ch1` will have a value immediately after the sync AJAX finished, and before you try to use it for the 1st time in the if

And I would also get rid of the `ch = function` and `ch = null`. Why do you have them?

Besides `ch1 !== Ch[0]` will be true after each AJAX response, even if the JSON hasn't changed! See:

```
a = {} ; b = {} ; console.log(a == b)
```

This is because you get a different object with a different reference, and even though their values are the same `==` doesn't compare them. Maybe this can help: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

And an even better solution would be to use Etag with http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Search for "ifModified" and "etag" in the link.

Comment: Yes, I need have ch1 !== ch[0] during initial load, because this will also load some features. Then, I want always save ch[number] (json data) into  variable ch+someNumber, which is executed few secs after new load of JSON. In the meanwhile, i want check wheteher there was any change.

Comment: If I use oldValues();, then ch[0] will be equivalent to ch1 during initial load and some parts of my app will not displayed.

Comment: then: if (ch1 && ch && ch[0] && ch1 !== ch[0])

Comment: See also my update why ch1 !== ch[0] will not do what you intend IMHO